# Playwright JS: How do I convert my test files/code/directory from Jest test runner to Playwright test runner?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, config, playwright, test-runner

1- File names are like login.test.js but in playwright test runner file name should be login.spec.js

2- Directory is Login(Component) -> specs -> login.test.js but in playwright test runner it should be like tests/login.spec.js

3- In my code I use jest keywords for example **describe** but in Playwright test runner it is **test.describe**

4- The playwright test runner config file is not supported in my project because it uses Module export. It gives error while reading config file.

So in this situation how can I move my project to Playwright Test Runner?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Not really. By default, Playwright Test runs `.*(test|spec)`
2. In Playwright Test's config you can specify a directory that will be recursively scanned for test files. Use `testDir` property for that.
3. Yep, you have to add `test` prefix for almost all methods such as `describe, test, beforeAll, beforeEach, afterAll, afterEach`.
4. I believe that issue was fixed in this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/pull/7328)